# xperfview on a different computer

Tags: xperf

Most use cases I've seen with xperf involve using xperfview on the same computer. A remote record and play back for me don't seem to work well. Symbols are not resolved correctly. Is there a known issue with remote record and local play with xperf/xperfview?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you try remote connection? if you use `xperf -d` to stop logging the ETL contains all metadata, so that the symbols can be loaded from any PC you want. Copy it from PC A to PC B and view the ETL there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. I did see comments on proper stopping on the xperf page at MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the 8.1 version of WPT is out, the recommended way to record traces is not with xperf.exe but with wprui.exe. This makes trace recording much simpler and much less error prone. See this blog post for details:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/xperf-basics-recording-a-trace-the-easy-way/

And yes, you absolutely should be able to record traces on one machine and view them on another.